# general formulation for 1/g(x) derivative

Tags: derivatives

Is there a general formulation for $\frac {d^n(g(x)^{-1})}{dx^n}$ ?
Something like $$\frac {d^n(g(x)^{-1})}{dx^n} = \sum_{i=1}^{f(n)}\prod_{k=1}^{h(n)} ...$$

Comment: do yoo mean $1/g(x)$ or the inverse function $g^{-1}$?

Comment: 1/g(x) (The inverse is $g^{-1}(x)$, if I'm not mistaken.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the formula of [Faà di Bruno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula)

[image]

with $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: thanks and may I add this [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FaadiBrunosFormula.html)